# merge two data as small data all goes in larger data

Tags: r

Dim of my first df1 is 6825 by 486, and second df2 is 188 by 10075. I want merge in a way that all all df2 goes in df1, is there any way to do in r? Final data should be 6825 by 10561 (486+10075)

Comment: `?merge`. Beyond that it's hard to help without a more reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You may need `full_join`

Comment: what is `df`, table?

Comment: df is dataframe, there is one column common in both df